# How i can add static files (css) to django web project

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have tested to embedded css style into html template, but it doesn't load css files, my configure as below, could you please help assist ?

checkstatic\showstatic\templates\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% load static%}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mystyle.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="{% static 'logo1.png' height="200" width="200" class="d-inline-block align-top" %}" alt="">
        <h1 class="test">hahahaha</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

checkstatic\static\css\mystyle.css

```
.test{
    color: red;
}
```

my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'showstatic'
]
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'checkstatic/static/')
]
```

when i access the index site, it only apply h1 tag, it can not load red color as the css config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statics are used to get and use complete files (css, images, js, etc), in your image it should be:

```
<img src="{% static 'logo1.png' %}" height="200" width="200" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
```

Leaving the properties of the img outside the static block.

Comment: hi , @Alejandro Franco, how about css format, my config in HTML is         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mystyle.css' %}"> , but it doen't apply the css format, do you know why ?

Comment: Have you set your URLs for media and static (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)?? 
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

first you should create directory=> static*
after then add base directory in setting:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / 'directory_name'] // typically the name is: static_root
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media')
```

then: insert urls in main project

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

!!attention !! ==> you should insert {%load static %} at above each of html pages
if you want to know more, follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/